# EV3 MonoBrick C# Library Tutorial

Tags: c#, visual-studio, lego-mindstorms

I'm wondering whether there are tutorials available for the programming of the MonoBrick EV3 library for C# for Visual Studio. I've seen one, but it is written in German language.

Comment: This should be posted [here](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Bobthezealot from my understanding "find tutorial for me" is unlikely to be on-topic on robotics as that site  have similar policy to SO in relation to searching for libraries/tutorials/books.

Comment: Well, I need to learn how to program the brick. Since my prof. didn't provide me with such tutorial, and I didn't find any tutorials online yet, then how should I learn how to program it? I'm not asking you to program for me. I'm asking if you know tutorials available online and/or you know how to program the EV3, then show me something (for now, I'm looking for how to move any of the motors). Isn't that a site for learning?

Answer (score 2):

You can check [monobrick.dk](http://www.monobrick.dk/software/ev3firmware/). Their main page has a Getting Started section, a Sample Program section, and links to examples. Lots and lots of examples, including:

- Motor synchronization
- SQLite support
- USB support

Comment: This answer micht be outdated because the link gives a 404 response.